# JavaCV (OpenCV) dot matrix character improvement

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I have been stuck since last 2 weeks (I have done enough R&D) in recognizing characters from scanned document having dot matrix characters. I am using tess4j (Tesseract) Java library for recognizing characters. As tess4j does not support or working well with dot matrix characters as the characters are made with dots separated by gaps while training.

So, I have decided to do:

1. Some image processing on scanned image using JavaCV (Open CV) java library.
2. Using Adobe illustrator, create svg for each characters from image created by JavaCV. (I don't know why traced svg images looks different than original)
3. Create font from all a-z svgs.
4. Train tesseract for this font and recognize characters.

Till now, I am getting 60-65% of accuracy in recognizing text.

I am pretty sure, I must be doing something wrong in JavaCV as I am very very novice in that. Previously I was using simple pixel based image processing and I found it very bad, and found that JavaCV (OpenCV) is best open-source library for Image Processing.

Till now my updated JavaCV Code:

```
Imgproc.resize(Main, Main, new Size(900, 200));
Imgproc.threshold(Main, Main, 200, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);
Imgproc.threshold(Main, Main, 200, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
```

Check attachment for scanned images:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfNqr.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czr3r.jpg)

How can I get clear type and joined text characters image?

Comment: What is the problem with `Imgproc.threshold(Main, Main, 200, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);`, what are your current results and what are expected results ?

Comment: It does not let me upload more than 2 images here, Please check this output images (1)https://ibb.co/c6sNbQ (2)https://ibb.co/h62cAk and this is the traced characters in adobe illustrator https://ibb.co/kAHAVk